# Building AMD64+mac Linux Images

Tags: linux, kernel, kali-linux, boot-loader, macintosh

I am looking for information on how to incorporate bootloader support for a 2006 MacBookPro2,1 into different Linux Distros. This version of the MBP was unique in that it featured a 64-bit processor architecture with a 32-bit EFI. This makes for tons' o fun (read: frustration) when trying to boot/install other OS's. A few distros (Ubuntu namely) used to feature AMD64+mac images that contained the necessary kernel and bootloader to be able to boot successfully on this platform. I would like to know the process for building these images so I can make my own bootable images for other distros. I would greatly appreciate insight and information from anyone who has experience with this process. Thanks!

Comment: I have never attempted this with my arch (never had a mac) but the arch wiki ([apart from swearing about the older Macs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_Firmware_bitness)) suggests to [disable UEFI capabilities of the boot image](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Remove_UEFI_boot_support_from_Optical_Media)

Comment: Thank you for that information! Looks like it might be a start.